# BadMethodCallException Unknown method, request in functions.php line 324

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

when I'm trying login in my localhost page
I received this error... what can I do?
I added web.php for login page
when I wanna login, I receive this error...

*at GuzzleHttp\deprecation_proxy(object(Client), 'request', array('POST', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', array('form_params' => array('secret' => '6Lfwbd4ZAAAAALakhzP4A0eGXtMvTbVhsc61kX9L', 'response' => '03AGdBq25tZskNVGKBFT7ci0AbOyoW0mjG0db15S1gcCsXTiNc5s8s90oHWtPuMDmbZ4fBGLQjdGBs1e_T8HatNIklMLGm6PKC4wOrHGki-EN3k0wuWEaDl1DA_D0cPwwBIzMnZ4WsFmm_OvTJYNGmDxXnmCJt1r-qr6-0vbT4GjoqbmWYNmSjScMWYNzxN_Kg435F0OiTZRAH6Wf9m1ko0ofj51EKYQt0kirBkU5O92VGttF5Jnv6GC_rjQROl9ED6wVZax4yBVuo22g4kpjqiGGX94gBfy3r0kDuxFqJD5IksSbNZfYqFi_K_cscgzL1YwSv8LeFx2LKrgrG3QSIhT7HKSEJ-4jURrml2qoKr5Akmy1lgeNtdLDAg9ZWvv92HmOdQ3DMes3lplt1v5GS8OK2Gl8ZTBBSSrgElmiayCYufSO2baUtltE', 'remoteip' => '127.0.0.1'))), array('getEventDispatcher' => 'getEmitter'))
in Client.php line 109*

composer.jason:

```
"cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "4.2.*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^4.2.4",
    "intervention/image": "^2.5",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "2.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "morilog/jalali": "^2.2",
    "uxweb/sweet-alert": "^2.0"
```

web.php:

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'Auth'],function (){

    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'LoginController@login');
    $this->get('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

AppservicePeovider.php:

```
public function boot()
{ Validator::extend('recaptcha' , function ($attribute , $value , $parameters , $validator){
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', [
             'form_params' => [
                'secret' => config('services.recaptcha.secret'),
                'response' => $value,
                'remoteip' => request()->ip()
            ]
        ]);
        $response = json_decode($response->getBody());
        return $response->success;
    });

}
```

Comment: you need to specify in more detail that which line of code or which function you are calling which is giving you this error

Comment: when I use guzzle for recaptcha in login page, I receive this error

Comment: in AppServiceProvider.php why don't recognize request method?

Comment: try providing complete path for client, `new \GuzzleHttp\Client()`, also shouldn't it be `Request::ip();` instead of `$request()->ip()`

Comment: please post full error, which plugin are you using for recaptcha?

Answer (score 0):

I can fixed this problem with change version of guzzle but at first I have to change version of socialite package because this version of guzzle depends on socialite version.

1. composer remove laravel/socialite 2.0
2. composer remove guzzlehttp/guzzle
3. composer require laravel/socialite 3.0
4. composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^6.3